# Websocket Client in Electron App delaying reception

Tags: vue.js, websocket, electron

I am using a websocket to push data from a process (running in the background) to my electron application (renderer, it's a electron-vue app). Mostly this works great, the data is received and displayed instantly.

In some cases, however, I noticed that the websocket client seemed to buffer incoming messages and only trigger the receive-event after some delay, leading to messages received as a batch.

To verify that the server isn't buffering anything I ran a second connection and simply logged the data (chrome-addon), there all the data is received and processed instantly while my electron application delays the messages.

I am using `ReconnectingWebsocket` but also tried a plain websocket application:

```
let webSocket = new WebSocket('ws://0.0.0.0:7700')
webSocket.onopen = function(openEvent) {
  console.log('WebSocket OPEN: ' + JSON.stringify(openEvent, null, 4))
}
webSocket.onclose = function(closeEvent) {
  console.log('WebSocket CLOSE: ' + JSON.stringify(closeEvent, null, 4))
}
webSocket.onerror = function(errorEvent) {
  console.log('WebSocket ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(errorEvent, null, 4))
}
webSocket.onmessage = function(messageEvent) {
  var wsMsg = messageEvent.data
  console.log('WebSocket MESSAGE: ' + wsMsg)
}
```

The `WebSocket MESSAGE:` is only displayed with some delay. Is there any configuration option, like buffering on the client side or must the render process be called more often..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it wasn't the websocket implementation but electron blocking the renderer process completely while scrolling, thus the delayed reception. I had to move the websocket connection out of the renderer and tunnel all messages using the IPC system.

Comment: How did you create a seperate process for websocket ? was it a hidden renderer.

Comment: I did not create a separate process, I just moved the websocket handling to the main process.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the solution but we have a demo app using Vue + Electron at https://github.com/firesharkstudios/butterfly-server-dotnet/tree/master/Butterfly.Example.Todo that also uses WebSockets.  I've never seen a delay or buffering like you are seeing.  Maybe you can compare the implementations to find a cause.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! I got a step further - it seems that it is related to scrolling: The rendering and even the ws-client appears to be blocked while I am scrolling - until the scrollbar disappears again, then all messages arrive in a batch and the view is updated. I couldn't find any options so far and I haven't had those issues in a pure Vue.js webapp so I guess it is related to electron. Any ideas there?

Comment: @martin it is possible that you are doing to much in the main process. Someone in a talk said it's a common mistake to do to much in the main process as it blocks everything.

Comment: @TheFool I was trying to use a websocket client in the renderer. To be specific: I'm using VueJS and there's websocket plugins for that. This would not work nicely though since electron would block the renderer while scrolling, messages would thus not arrive while scrolling. I removed the websocket from the renderer and now feed everything into vuex.